# Implement different clickable Area on an image-page through image map

Tags: android, imagemap

```
                                A B C D
                                E F G H  --figure.
```

I am working on Book App on Android. In my book App, there are many images-pages. In first image-page there are 26 alphabets(A-Z),4 alphabets in  a raw(as shown in my picture).

My Problem is:

1. I want to developed a click-able area for each and every alphabets (A-Z) . when user click or touch on any of alphabet then a square box should be appear like  "image A is clicked"(shown in above figure).
2. On every touch or click on alphabets images(A-Z) i  will pass corresponding sound. Means i want to call different-different Listeners for different-different area on a single image-page.

i have no idea  about how to implement click-able area on an image  which click able area or coordinates doesn't vary emulator to emulator.

please provide me some sample code or an idea or reference link.

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I remember answering a very similar question just a few days ago. In order to implement this as the image, you'll need to know what areas of the image mean what (i.e. if you get coordinates of of a touch event, which action these coordinates would correspond to).  Provided you have this info, you can then register `OnTouchListener` with your ImageView:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();
        //now deal with coordinates (x, y)
    }
});
```

However in your case, I would suggest using a layout with 26 buttons and just use `OnClickListener` with each of them.  You can easily set the buttons up in the shape you want and you can easily set individual background drawables to them to make it look as one whole image.

Comment: Thanks for answer,but i have a image-page that contains 26 (A-Z) alphabets image.but in my 2nd page there are many picture like comics,so i want to display a thin border area around the click-able of image and one notification should come like you click this area or image with sound.how to implement all thing altogether please give me some sample code or link.  Thanks.